# I have to add blinking pipe into an specific placeholder

Tags: javascript, css, sass, liquid, placeholder

I need to include a blinking pipe (as if it were a cursor) at the end of my placeholder. It is a component in liquid code.

I tried to pass a variable with the blinking content through javascript and more recently an infinite animation of 1s in my sass file, but there is no way to do that and I don't know how.

This is my input:

```
<input type="email"
 name="contact[email]"
 id="{{ formId }}-email"
 class="input-group__field{% if form.errors %} input--error{% endif %}"
 value="{{ form.email }}"
 placeholder="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.email_placeholder' | t }}"
 {% if form.errors %}
  aria-invalid="true"
  aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-email-error"
  data-form-status
 {% endif %}
>
```

I can't add via css the animation like this

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
}
blink {
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

because i can't asign a class or id only in some part of placeholder

Maybe something like this in sass could be work?

`input[type="email"] { animation: blink 1s step-start 0s infinite; }`

I think to try to concatenate a variable through liquid and make the javascript call but it doesn't work for me either... Any tip?

Comment: can you not just use js to focus() on the input (or does the cursor have to be at the end of the placeholder text)?

Comment: @lucas The cursor have to be at the end of the text. If it were in the whole text I don't think I had this problem

Comment: you obviously know your circumstances better than me, but I would be wary of this approach as it breaks the generally accepted UI of the browser. If people see a blinking cursor in a text input, the logical assumption is that they can start typing and text will appear

Comment: Totally agree! But i need that blinking pipe precisely because currently is doesn't appear in write field. The currently design is this https://fotos.subefotos.com/7307dc01ddeac05777a2a6cf74e15705o.png

Comment: @lucas has a great point.

Comment: where is the input? where it says direccion de email?

Comment: @Lucas it is preprocessed by another file via id: `id="{{ formId }}-email"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately to get what you want you'll need to compromise a bit and just give the *illusion* you're after. Which may take a little tweaking per instance but you could use javascript to cheat and make it more generic but hopefully this example gives a decent starting place, cheers!

```js
let tempPlaceholder = '';

cleanUp = (me) => {
  const thePlaceHolder = me.parentElement;
  tempPlaceholder = thePlaceHolder.getAttribute('data-placeHolder');
  thePlaceHolder.setAttribute('data-placeholder', '');
}

putItBack = (me) => {
  if (!me.value) {
    const thePlaceHolder = me.parentElement;
    thePlaceHolder.setAttribute('data-placeholder', tempPlaceholder);
    tempPlaceholder = '';
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes typing { from { width: 0; } }
@keyframes blink-caret { 50% { border-color: transparent; } }

aside {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

aside:after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  top: .25rem;
  left: .5rem;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  color: #555;
  width: 22em; /* IE fallback */
  width: 16ch;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: typing 2s steps(22, end),
      blink-caret .5s step-end infinite alternate;
}

input {
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}
```

```html
<aside id="placeholder" data-placeholder="I am a placeholder...">
 <input type="text" aria-labelledby="placeholder" onfocus="cleanUp(this)" onfocusout="putItBack(this)">
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the input does not focus in the snippet, but this works OK in the browser

```js
var inpt = document.getElementById("inp"),
  dv = document.getElementById("dv");
inpt.focus();
inpt.onkeypress = dv.onclick = function() {
  dv.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "";
  inpt.focus()
}
inpt.onkeyup = inpt.onblur = function() {
  if (inpt.value == "") {
    dv.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Placeholder";
    setTimeout(function() {
      inpt.focus();
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

```css
#dv {
  display: inline-block;
}

#inp {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="dv">
  Placeholder
  <input id="inp">
</div>
```